# Are the two random variables independent?

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-process, queueing-theory

Consider the following two random variables,

In first case you record the number of people arriving at a queue, for a random amount of time. Note, here the arrival of people in the queue is random (governed by Poisson distribution) and the amount of time the queue is observed is also random. Denote the number of people observed here by $N(T)$

In second case you record the number of people arriving in same queue, for fixed amount of time $t_1$. Denote this by $N(t_1)$.

Is $N(T)$ independent of $N(t_1)$ ? In general, if we observe a set queues (not just a single queue) will the two random variables recording the total number of people arrived across all the queues, be independent?

Comment: The _same_ queue, observed during _overlapping_ windows of time?  If so, how can they be independent?  E.g. imagine $T \sim N(t_1, \sigma)$ for some very small $\sigma$, then there will be very high prob that $N(T) = N(t_1)$.  OTOH if the time windows do not overlap, e.g. you do the $T$ observation first, have a cup of coffee, then do the $t_1$ observation, then sure they will be independent if the queue arrivals are memoryless.

Comment: @antkam thanks for your intuitive answer. In the application I am considering it is the second case and independence will make life much easier.

Comment: If the queue is memoryless, then any two disjoint windows will be independent, if the window lengths themselves are also independent of everything else.  (I mean, if you do $t_1$ first, and then the value of $T$ actually depends on $N(t_1)$, then of course you lose independence...)